# response.sendRedirect() doesn't redirect properly

Tags: java, servlets

I have a `response.sendRedirect()` in an `if` statement, linking to a link generated by `string.format`:

```
String redirect = String.format("booking?order_id=%d&complete='0'&date='%s'&timePeriod='%s'&totalPrice=%d", intBookingID, date, timePeriod, intTotalPrice);
```

however this generates a 500 error instead or linking to the requested page, is this because I have used parameters, and If so how else would I do this?

Comment: Your code threw an exception. Find it and its stacktrace in server logs and fix code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It takes absolute address you need to add `/your-web-context/` ahead

Answer (score 0):

[Http 500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_codes#5xx_Server_Error) code is **Internal Server Error** which means that something didn't go well in your server. I recommend you to check your logs and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the string `redirect`? You should call `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` but you **must not** call `setStatus()`, `setContentType()`, `setContentLength()`, `setCharacterEncoding()`, `getOutputStream()` or `getWriter()` on the `HttpServletResponse` before **or** after `sendRedirect()` as the API says:

> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException.

Is there any additional message in the 500 error page or in the log of the server? 500 (Internal Server Error) is typically an uncaught exception.